# check if vector b = [3 2] is in the column space of A

Tags: linear-algebra

so I'm trying to prove by setting up a augmented matrix with vector b [3 2] is in col(A). I am trying to find if vector b spans col(A).

$$A =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \\1 & 1& 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

so the augmented matrix is:

$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r} 1 & 0 & -1 & 3\\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 \end{array}\right]$$

so what I start by is row reducing and get:

$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r} 1 & 0 & -1 & 3\\ 0 & 1 & 2 & -1 \end{array}\right]$$

but from here it looks like I can't get linear independence, but my book says this is in col(A). Can someone show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: What is A and respectively col(A) ?

Comment: @brick A is the matrix left of the 2 " | " to see if the matrix is a basis I must see if vector b is in the columns of A.

Comment: If you trying to prove that $(3, 2)$ is a linear combination of the columns of $А$, then it's obvious since the first and the second column are linearly independent and therefore form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what linear independence has to do with anything here. You've shown that every row has a pivot, so $\text{Col}(A)$ spans all of $\mathbb R^2$, including $b$. Indeed, we can explicitly express $b$ as a linear combination of the original columns of $A$ by inspection:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3 \\ 2
\end{bmatrix}
=
3\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
+ (-1)
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
+ 0
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: I'm trying to find out if vector v is in the basis for the matrix A